# Regex Version of Strip() - Automate the Boring Stuff with Python

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying to learn how to code with Al Sweigert's book. Right now I'm stuck in making the program get the text and/or the argument from a single input. I know it's simpler to use two separate inputs, but I want to make it using just one.

I also don't know what's the difference between r' and rf' in Regex.

```
#python 3
#A program that does exactly the same thing as the split function  
import re
def striperoo(text, argument):
    if argument != '':
        argRegex = re.compile(rf'{argument}')
        while True:
            argCheck = argRegex.search(text)
            if argCheck != None:
                startOfArg = argCheck.span()[0]
                endOfArg = argCheck.span()[1]
                text = text[:startOfArg] + text[endOfArg:]
            else:
                print(text)
                break
    else:
        spcRegexBegin = re.compile(r'^\s+')
        spcRegexEnd = re.compile(r'\s+$')
        while True:
            spcAtBeginning = spcRegexBegin.search(text)
            spcAtEnd = spcRegexEnd.search(text)
            if spcAtBeginning != None:
                blankSpacesSpan = spcAtBeginning.span()[1]
                text = text[blankSpacesSpan:]
            elif spcAtEnd != None:
                spacesAtEnd = spcAtEnd.span()[0]
                text = text[:spacesAtEnd]
            else:
                print(text)
                break

texto, argumento = input('Please type text and argument using the format text, argument: ').split(', ')
striperoo(texto, argumento)
```

Could somebody give me a hand? As expected, when I type just one variable the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\strip.py", line 33, in <module>
    texto, argumento = input('Please type text and argument using the format text, argument: ').split(', ')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

It should transform strings like `'   Hola mundo cruel   '` to `'Hola mundo cruel'` and `'AholaAmundoAcruel, A'` to `'holamundocruel'`.

Thanks,

Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is not `', '` in user input `.split` would produce list with 1 element, you might check it at act accordingly

```
userinput = input('Please type text and argument using the format text, argument: ').rsplit(', ', maxsplit=1)
if len(userinput) == 1:
    texto, argumento = userinput[0], ''
else:
    texto, argumento = userinput
```

Note that I use `rsplit` with `maxsplit` set to `1`, which mean it will give `list` of `len` not greater than `2`, when `split` without maxsplit might give longer list. This mean that if user input has more than one `', '` it will be split only at rightmost one.

Comment: That was great! It worked like a charm. Thank you so much!